# Session is closed when I use Query as a result value

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using a Web method that call an other class in this way:

```
    @WebMethod
public List <User> findUser(
        ) throws Exception {

    List <User> resultList = new LinkedList<User>();
    Iterator iterUser = queryF.searchUser().getResultList().iterator();
    while (iterUser .hasNext()){
        Users u = (Users ) iterUser .next();
        resultList.add(u.getUser());
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

NB: queryF is an EJB of the class QueryF

The other class QueryF is this :

```
   @Stateless
   @Proxy(lazy = false)
   public class QueryF{
    EntityManager em3;
    public Query searchUser() throws Exception{

    Query q = em3.createQuery("FROM users");
    if(q.getResultList().isEmpty()){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return q;
}
}
```

And the result of this webmethod is "org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!"
The strange thing is if I use List instead of Query of the result of the method (searchUser) it works... why? What am I doing wrong?

The stranger thing is If I use query in two different classes and with other tables I don't have this problem...

Answer (score 0):

It is because the database transaction is scoped around your stateless EJB. The result List is now accessed outside the database transaction.

Comment: so the only solution is to use List instead of Query ?

Comment: Not really, it's dependent on the transaction scope of your EJB. You are calling your EJB from the web-tier via your findUser WebMethod. If you annotate the calling class with Stateless too you would extend the scope where the transaction begins and ends. You could wrap your EJB within another Stateless EJB which would allow you to access the Query's methods inside the transaction.

Comment: there is no transaction in the 2 classes

Comment: The transaction is implicitly defined for each EJB.